# Xlib extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, midori

I'm using VPS and have installed vncserver on it.
When I run "midori" it always produces this error:

```text
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
1   0x7f28c1a3d9e5 /usr/lib/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0.so.0(_ZN3WTF11OSAllocator16reserveAndCommitEmNS0_5UsageEbbb+0xc5) [0x7f28c1a3d9e5]
2   0x7f28c1a3bf1f /usr/lib/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0.so.0(_ZN3JSC19ExecutableAllocator19initializeAllocatorEv+0x8f) [0x7f28c1a3bf1f]
3   0x7f28c1978af5 /usr/lib/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0.so.0(_ZN3JSC19initializeThreadingEv+0x25) [0x7f28c1978af5]
4   0x7f28c20915ca /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(webkitInit+0x7a) [0x7f28c20915ca]
5   0x7f28c20a37ef /usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0(+0x3c47ef) [0x7f28c20a37ef]
6   0x7f28c5a24627 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_class_ref+0x4d7) [0x7f28c5a24627]
7   0x7f28c5a24595 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_class_ref+0x445) [0x7f28c5a24595]
8   0x7f28c5a0ccac /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_newv+0x85c) [0x7f28c5a0ccac]
9   0x7f28c5a0d1ec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_new+0xec) [0x7f28c5a0d1ec]
10  0x7f28c5e8d4ed midori(+0x234ed) [0x7f28c5e8d4ed]
11  0x7f28c5e8eaff midori(main+0xd5f) [0x7f28c5e8eaff]
12  0x7f28c08c676d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f28c08c676d]
13  0x7f28c5e905a1 midori(+0x265a1) [0x7f28c5e905a1]
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

The vnc server you're using does not provide support for dynamically resizing/rotating the screen. midori seems to require this.

You should use a specific vnc server that supports this extension e.g. [vnc4server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816/changing-the-resolution-of-a-vnc-session-in-linux/3839759), and the exception will not be thrown.

Comment: So - it appears that vnc4server is no longer available via Ubuntu apt-get - any other suggestions?

Comment: It should be in universe - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vnc4server (I have no idea what version of ubuntu you're using, but if it's in trusty, it's probably in your release)

Comment: Petesh - thanks - but I'm trying to get this running in 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin and the package does not seem to be available on an ARM processor and the build from source fails...

Comment: You downloaded the source package using `apt-get source vnc4server`? there may be patches that prevent it from being compiled on Precise that need to be worked around. You should ask another question to see if someone can help you build it.